# QWidget::geometry() vs. QWidget::frameGeometry()

Tags: qt, qt4

Although [Qt's docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/application-windows.html#window-geometry) indicate that these two functions are different (the first doesn't include the frame) no matter what widget I choose - including the main window of my application - `someWidget->frameGeometry().height()` always returns the same value as `someWidget->geometry.height()`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, you don't give enough time to widget to be painted. There is little example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow() {
        startTimer(500);
    }

    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *e) {
        // Here values are different
        qDebug() << geometry().height() << frameGeometry().height();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow mainWin;
    mainWin.show();

    // Here values are equals
    qDebug() << mainWin.geometry().height() << mainWin.frameGeometry().height();

    return app.exec();
}
```

First debug output will produce the same values for `geometry` and `frameGeometry`, but the second (in `timerEvent`) will produce different.

Comment: Thanks for the illustration -- very helpful.

Comment: @Planarian but I don't know, how long time _exactly_ it takes to be _completely_ painted :(

Answer (score 1):

The QWidget class cannot have a frame. For example, QWidget doesn't have a frame, but QFrame has a frame.

Comment: But don't plenty of QWidgets have them? QMdiSubWindow, for instance, doesn't inherit QFrame

Answer (score 1):

if QWidget is toplevel window then you can see borders and title bar around it. We call it frame or decoration frame and frameGeometry() returns exactly that: window size and position which includes OS decorations.On the other side geometry() returs QWidget inner rect which is available for other child controls or painting.See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/application-windows.html#window-geometry for more details.Toplevel geometry() / frameGeometry() differs if our window is not frameless or fullscreen ... or we are talking about some frameless window manager under x11.

Answer (score 1):

this is an old post, but that could help those searching for the same problem.

Just call

```
adjustSize();
```

before prompting for some geometry attributes

Answer (score 0):

As user *fasked* notes, `frameGeometry()` may not include the frame margins early in the window creation lifecycle. I have found that the following code works in some situations where calling `frameGeometry()` does not.

```
QMargins frameMargins;
QWindow *window = widget->windowHandle();
if (window) {
    window->create();
    frameMargins = window->frameMargins();
}

QRect myFrameGeometry = widget->geometry().adjusted( 
        -frameMargins.left(), -frameMargins.top(),
        frameMargins.right(), frameMargins.bottom());
```