# How to Align mainwindow to the right of the screen in Qt 5.1.0

Tags: c++, qt, alignment, screen

This code is working :

```
QRect r = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry();
QRect main_rect = this->geometry();
main_rect.moveTopRight(r.topRight());
this->move(main_rect.topLeft());
```

This code is working on position of screen.. But I want to **align** to the right of screen..

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use setAlignment to your main layout something like this

```
QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
mainLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
```

Comment: go to Design and click somewhere on MainWindow, then in properties window find layoutDirection and change it to RightToLeft

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but sadly it's not that easy...

First, you have to do the movement after a short delay, you can read more about it [here (Check the accepted answere)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540075/qwidgetgeometry-vs-qwidgetframegeometry)

And what you have to do to move the window is the following:

```
void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{

    if(event->timerId() == this->TimerID)
    {
        event->accept();
        this->killTimer(this->TimerID);
        //Used to kill the timer that was created in the constructor, needs the ID to do this

        QRect desktopGeom = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry(); //Screen size
        QRect windowFrame = this->frameGeometry(); //Window with frame
        QRect windowSize = this->geometry(); //Window without frame

        int smallFrameFactor = (windowFrame.width() - windowSize.width()) / 2; //Because the left, right and bottom border have the same size
        int wideFrameFactor = windowFrame.height() - (windowSize.height() + smallFrameFactor); //The big, upper border

        int x_pos = desktopGeom.x() + desktopGeom.width() - windowSize.width() - smallFrameFactor;
        int y_pos = desktopGeom.y() + wideFrameFactor;

        this->setGeometry(x_pos, y_pos, windowSize.width(), windowSize.height());
    }
    else
        event->ignore();
}
```

I added a picture, to vizualize what I did above. I hope I was able to help you.

EDIT: Just saw this question is over a year old... By maybe it's still helpful for someone...

[image: Example Image]